# How can we get a long value larger than 10^20 in Java, as suggested in Sedgewick's Algorithms 4th edition, p. 778?

Tags: java, long-integer

When talking about the implementation of Rabin-Karp, Robert Sedgewick's and Kevin Wayne's *"Algorithms - Fourth Edition"*, chapter 5.3 "Substring Search" on page 778 states:

> We will use a `long` value greater than 10^20, making the probability that a random key hashes to the same value as our pattern less than 10^(-20), an exceedingly small value.

However, 10^20 appears to be *larger* than `Long.MAX_VALUE` of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 or **2^63 - 1**.

How can therefore "a `long` value greater than 10^20" be used?

Comment: You can't, not as a Java `long` at least.

Comment: Are you sure it's "We will use a `long` value" and not "We will use a **long** value"...? (i.e. large). You can use `BigInteger` to represent numbers bigger than you could with a primitive long.

Comment: The word "long" is in different typeface from the rest of the sentence, and in the code the variable q is declared as `private long q;`, so I'm reasonably certain the book is referring to the literal type `long` as opposed to just the length of the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long` is not able too store you're right

---

- These can :

  ```
  float f  = 10000000000000000000f;  
  double d = 10000000000000000000d; 
  BigInteger bigI = new BigInteger("100000000000000000000");
  BigDecimal bigD = new BigDecimal("100000000000000000000");
  ```
- These can't

  ```
  byte b  = 10000000000000000000;    
  short s = 10000000000000000000; 
  int i   = 10000000000000000000;    
  long l  = 10000000000000000000L;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigInteger` if you work with a long. This can be as long as you want

You can also use a  `BigDecimal`  when working with floating point numbers.